# Sass @use ordering

Tags: css, sass

I have some styles:

**tokens.scss**

```
.text-center {
  text-align:center;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@mixin text-style-1 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**component/card.scss**

```
@use "../token.scss" as tokens;

.card {
  @include tokens.text-style-1;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

**index.scss**

```
// import components
@use component/card.scss

// import tokens
@use tokens.scss
```

When I compile *index.scss* I would like the styles from *tokens.scss* to be included after my component styles, but because I @use the mixins from *tokens.scss* in my components it's always imported before and not in the order defined in *index.scss*.

Is there anyway to just include the mixins from *tokens.scss* without importing all the styles before my components? Or is there anyway to define an import ordering when using @use?

The only way I've found to fix this issue is by replacing @use with @import in *index.scss*, but this obviously duplicates the styling which isn't ideal.

Comment: You should separate your styling, mixins and variables in separate files and just use them when you need them. Also, instead of using this "use "../token.scss" as tokens;" do it like this "use "../token.scss" as *;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is take the mixin in a separate file. Unfortunatly, `@import` and `@use` will bring the styling with them.

From the [SASS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)

```
// src/_corners.scss
$radius: 3px;

@mixin rounded {
  border-radius: $radius;
}
```

And then

```
// style.scss
@use "src/corners" as c;

.button {
  @include c.rounded;
  padding: 5px + c.$radius;
}
```

EDIT : added the ouput

```
.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: This was my solution in the end. It's a shame Sass doesn't support an import statement which just brings in the mixins / vars without the styling. Thank you.

Comment: I think some globing tools can do it. See node-sass-magic-importer https://github.com/maoberlehner/node-sass-magic-importer